# Adding support for LESS-modules in Ant Design React Typescript project

Tags: typescript, antd

I have created new React Ant Design project, *with typescripts*, with  command:

```
$ create-react-app my-project --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts-antd
```

following the [official Ant Design documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-in-typescript#Alternative-way)

Now I want to add support for **LESS modules** in my project, without **ejecting**. I have tried to follow multiple articles on modifying `config-overrides.js` file, without any success. Anyone got this working and can share the configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many try/fails I figured this out, posting the answer if others are interested.

1. Install [react-app-rewire-less-modules](https://github.com/andriijas/react-app-rewire-less-modules) that is compatible with react-scripts-ts v2.16.0:

`$ yarn add react-app-rewire-less-modules@1.1.0 -D`

2. Add `config-overrides.js` with configuration for **ts-import-plugin** for component import on demand, **custom theming** and **LESS modules**

```js
// config-overrides.js
const tsImportPluginFactory = require('ts-import-plugin');
const { getLoader } = require('react-app-rewired');
const rewireLessModules = require('react-app-rewire-less-modules');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    const tsLoader = getLoader(
        config.module.rules,
        rule =>
            rule.loader &&
            typeof rule.loader === 'string' &&
            rule.loader.includes('ts-loader')
    );

    tsLoader.options = {
        getCustomTransformers: () => ({
            before: [ tsImportPluginFactory({
                libraryDirectory: 'es',
                libraryName: 'antd',
                style: true
            }) ]
        })
    };

    config = rewireLessModules.withLoaderOptions(
        `${env === 'production' ? 'wmf' : '[path][name]__[local]-'}-[hash:base64:8]`, {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
            modifyVars: { '@primary-color': '#1DA57A' }
        })(config, env);

    return config;
};
```

3. Declare `.css` and `.less` as Typescript modules in new file `style-modules.d.ts`, in order to use `import` in step #5

```js
// style-modules.d.ts
declare module '*.css';
declare module '*.less';
```

4. Create new file `App.module.less`

```less
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

5. Import LESS as module in `App.tsx`

```js
import { Button } from 'antd';
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import styles from './App.module.less';

class App extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
                <p className={styles.red}>
                    LESS Modules
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```